# SvelteKit / Javascript "x is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I have a fairly large SvelteKit project and these "x is not a function" error for some imported functions. E.g.:

/lib/controller/userController.js:

```
let userCache = {};

export const deleteUserCache = () => {
    userCache = {};
};
```

and in
/lib/controller/userGroupController.js

```
import { deleteUserCache } from '$lib/controller/userController';

export const reloadUserGroupArrayAccess = async () => {
    deleteUserCache();
};
```

shows the error

> [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/lib/controller/userGroupController.js:
> TypeError: **vite_ssr_import_0**.deleteUserCache is not a function

**BUT**

/lib/controller/userGroupController.js

```
import { deleteUserCache } from '$lib/controller/userController';

export const reloadUserGroupArrayAccess = async () => {
    if (deleteUserCache) {
        deleteUserCache();
    }
};
```

works fine.

What do I get wrong?

Comment: You are likely seeing this on your terminal, and `deleteUserCache` function depends on the window object. try 

`
if (browser && deleteUserCache) {
        deleteUserCache();
    }
`

Comment: As this is code is running on the server and not in the browser, there is no window object.